# How do I create a circular slide (similar to a water park slide)?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, screw-modifier

I have been trying to use a combination of bevel object and the screw modifier and I keep getting all kinds of interesting shapes but none are what I need.  I'm sure there is an easier way than just randomly adjusting parameters. Below is the best I've been able to do and that's after 45 minutes of fiddling about.

[image: slide attempt]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating a slide is a rather simple process. You can easily create a slide using two modifiers. Here is how its done.

**1. Create a curve to use as your path:**

- add a bezier curve and modify it

**2. Create a cross-sectional of the slide:**

- Use a polygon mesh instead of a curve object:

  - curves when converted to polygons are messy and you will need to do some manual clean up
  - you have easy control over the polygon count
- Make sure the cross-sectional has some depth to it, it should be a 3d mesh not a 2d outline or plane.
  [image]

**3. Add Array and Curve modifiers:**

- Select the cross sectional mesh and add an Array and Curve modifier
- Array modifier settings:

  - Fit Type: Fit Curve, this will fill the path out for us automatically
  - Merge: True, erases inside polygons

    [image]
- Curve modifier settings:

  - Object: select the curve

    [image]

**4. Fix the slide:**

- Based the curve the slide can oriented in the wrong way.

  [image]
- Select the curve and go into edit mode.
- Select the points of the curve that are messed up.
- Adjust the tilt using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

  [image]

Comment: That explains a lot.  Worked perfectly.  Thank you for the quick response.  I can now move on with my life

Comment: In your example with the check mark, there should not be internal faces in the cross-sectional of the slide.