# Creating a Downwards Slide

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

I was browsing Thingivese, and saw this model

:[image]

I was wondering, what would be the most effective way to design those downwards spirals/slides?

I have no idea of how to make something like it, as i have not seen many people try to do this, therefor making it nearly-impossible to create.

I know how to use blender, just not this particular side of it...

Thank you for your time and understanding

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7030/how-do-i-create-a-circular-slide-similar-to-a-water-park-slide

Comment: @zeffii I have tried nothing, as i could not find any resources...